# how to add stacked widgets that can be switched in pySimpleGUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

How to make stacked widgets that can be switched in PySimpleGUI, Like in react native we use navigation to stack screen one on the top of other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No stacked widgets available in PySimpleGUI, maybe you can use option `visible`  with value `True` or `False` to switch between different elements.

Comment: Why does this have tkinter as one of the tags